# Add new Row in editable state

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, inline-editing

I have a simple repeater in which each row can be edited in-line. As part of that repeater, when I add a new row I would like it to be in the editable state, not static. When I tried adding the $scope.editable = true to the Add Button, it makes the entire repeater editable.

Here's a plunker illustrating my code:
http://plnkr.co/edit/tVOLYm2mg5be2L6NpM6k?p=preview

```
$scope.addRow = function() {
    $scope.accounts.unshift({ name: 'Enter Name', id: 'Enter ID', code: 'Enter Code'});
    //$scope.editable = true;
}
```

Can anyone assist with what I'm trying to accomplish?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.editable = false;
```

This statement sets the editable value in the parent scope and ng-repeat makes child scope for every repeat.
You need to understand that concept.
[Look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42270597/ng-model-and-ng-repeat-relation-and-understanding-scope/42271122#42271122) to understand that.

Now, a better way to implement what you want to do is by adding a new property to every account object in your accounts array that makes a row editable or non editable.

So whenever unshifting an account, do as follows:

```
 $scope.accounts.unshift({
      name: 'Enter Name',
      id: 'Enter ID',
      code: 'Enter Code',
      editable: true
  });
```

and in html, instead of using `editable`, use `account.editable`

You don't need to add `editable` property to your existing data as non-existent properties are implicitly falsy, so your grid will automatically be in non-editable mode initially.

Comment: I see what you mean. I had tried adding that same code to my data and unshift script, but I didn't have it correct on html side, so wasn't working either. Much appreciation @Pranav Jindal!

Comment: Also, read the question and explanation to the question that I've hyperlinked. It'll really make you understand what's happening.