# How to work on ng-show for particular index in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-show

HTML:

```
        <div class="displayImgData col-sm-3" ng-repeat="item in profileData" >

          <a ng-show="onLoadFav" title="Make as Favourite"> 
             <img class="styleright" src="assets/images/unfavourite.png" ng-if="(item.favourite ==0)" ng-click="favouriteUser(item.userid);">
     </a>  

        <a ng-show="onLoadUnFav" title="Favourite"> 
    <img class="styleright" src="assets/images/favourite.png"  ng-if="(item.favourite ==1)" ng-click="unfavouriteUser(item.userid);" >`
     </a>`

        <a ng-show="newFav" title="Make as Favourite">  
    <img class="styleright" src="assets/images/unfavourite.png" ng-click="favouriteUser(item.userid);">
     </a> 

        <a ng-show="newUnFav" title="Favourite">
     <img class="styleright" src="assets/images/favourite.png"  ng-click="unfavouriteUser(item.userid);" > 
    </a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.onLoad = function(){
   $scope.profileData = [{'favourite':0,'userid':1},{'favourite':0,'userid':2},{'favourite':1,'userid':3}]
};
 $scope.onLoadFav = false;
$scope.onLoadUnFav = false;
$scope.newFav = false;
$scope.newUnFav = true; 
 $scope.unfavouriteUser= function(){
UserService.getSocialMedia(json).then(function (res) {   
   if(res.statuscode == 0){
    $scope.onLoadFav = false;
    $scope.onLoadUnFav = false;
    $scope.newFav = false;
    $scope.newUnFav = true;   
     } 
         });
  };
```

I have `onload()`which I call on loading my page, I will make my favourite.png enabled if `item.favourite == 1`in my `$scope.profileData` and unfavourite.png enabled if `item.favourite == 0`. If I want to make a particular record alone unfavourite . I am using `unfavourite()` and I get response from backend as success . If i call `onload()` again it will be like reloading entire page again.So I given `ng-show = onLoadFav ,onLoadUnFav, newFav, newUnFav`respectively in html to make it icon enabled accordingly., But the problem is , since it in ng-repeat all the icon is becoming enabled or disabled , not the particular one. How to work on ng-show for particular index in ng-repeat

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42270597/ng-model-and-ng-repeat-relation-and-understanding-scope/42271122#42271122 

Look at answer and detailed explanation for ng-repeat here

Answer (score 1):

I did not test the code, will do it soon. but you could use an array addressed by userid

```
<div class="container" ng-app="confusionApp">
  <div class="displayImgData col-sm-3" ng-controller="testCtrl" ng-repeat="item in profileData" >

    <a ng-show="loadData[item.userid].onLoadFav" title="Make as Favourite">
      <img class="styleright" src="assets/images/unfavourite.png" ng-if="(item.favourite ==0)" ng-click="favouriteUser(item.userid);">
    </a>

    <a ng-show="loadData[item.userid].onLoadUnFav" title="Favourite">
      <img class="styleright" src="assets/images/favourite.png"  ng-if="(item.favourite ==1)" ng-click="unfavouriteUser(item.userid);" >`
    </a>`

    <a ng-show="loadData[item.userid].newFav" title="Make as Favourite">
      <img class="styleright" src="assets/images/unfavourite.png" ng-click="favouriteUser(item.userid);">
    </a>

    <a ng-show="loadData[item.userid].newUnFav" title="Favourite">
      <img class="styleright" src="assets/images/favourite.png"  ng-click="unfavouriteUser(item.userid);" >
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And that would be the controller

```
angular.module('testApp',[])

    .controller('testCtrl',['$scope', function($scope) {

      $scope.loadData = [];

      $scope.onLoad = function(){
        $scope.profileData = [{'favourite':0,'userid':1},{'favourite':0,'userid':2},{'favourite':1,'userid':3}];

        for (var i=0; i < $scope.profileData.length; i ++ ) {
          $scope.loadData[$scope.profileData[i].userid] = {onLoadFav : false, onLoadUnFav : false, newFav: false, newUnFav : true};
        }

      };




      $scope.unfavouriteUser= function(pUserID){



        UserService.getSocialMedia(json).then(function (res) {
          if(res.statuscode == 0){
            $scope.loadData[pUserID].onLoadFav = false;
            $scope.loadData[pUserID].onLoadUnFav = false;
            $scope.loadData[pUserID].newFav = false;
            $scope.loadData[pUserID].newUnFav = true;
          }
        });
      };

      $scope.onLoad();

    }]);
```

Comment: Thank you , Let me check this method and see

Comment: okay now i have tested the code, seems to work. i missed $scope two times before variable, but i have updated this now.

Comment: Hi , I get favourite icon enabled for all the datas.

Comment: newUnFav is active for all data. and the newUnFav image is favorite.png. If you don't want to have it activated then set it on false in this line : for           $scope.loadData[$scope.profileData[i].userid] = {onLoadFav : false, onLoadUnFav : false, newFav: false, newUnFav : true};